# Smarty substr & strpos from last occurrence

Tags: php, smarty

```
{assign var="bar_at" value=$product.supplier_reference|strpos:"="}
```

The `$product.supplier_reference` looks like https://www.example.com/search?w=1366&h=610&q=the_actual_reference

I need to get what comes after the last '='(the actual reference)

How to get strpos after the last occurrence?

Comment: Guess you are looking for a combination of [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the right function to go with is : [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos)

you have various ways to accomplish this:

1- the pure smarty way:

```
{assign var="str" value="https://www.example.com/search?w=1366&h=610&q=the_actual_reference"}
{assign var="offset" value=$str|strrpos:"="}
{assign var="reference" value=$str|substr:($offset+1)}
{$reference}
```

---

2- create new plugin in the plugins directory , which lays under the following path : `vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/plugins/` , add new file with your new plugin name, lets say `function.getReference.php`

create a new function `smarty_function_getReference`

and write your pure PHP function, then use this from your smarty template directly like following :

```
function  smarty_function_money ($paramters) {
    $url = $paramters['url'];
    // here is our function body
}
```

within your smarty template:

```
{getReference url="https://www.example.com/search?w=1366&h=610&q=the_actual_reference"}
```

---

3- add new modifier:

where-ever you are defining your smarty view logic register the new modifier :

```
$callback = function ($string) {
    // perform your logic within this callback
};

$this->registerPlugin('modifier', 'getRefernce', $callback);
```

then call this modifier directly from your smarty template like following :

```
{"https://www.example.com/search?w=1366&h=610&q=the_actual_reference"|getRefernce}
```